# How to implement RBAC in react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mern, rbac

I want to implement RBAC in my React project and here I have different role Like ADMIN,SUPERADMIN etc. and I am storing that user role in LocalStorage and showing information according to the user role so what actually happening that if user is ADMIN that store in localStorage have only access to limited things but when he change its role to SuperAdmin from localstorage from dev or console he get all the access of SuperAdmin what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

You can Create one `Middleware` so every route `passed` or `render` from that Middleware and It's a better way to you can use API's call in your middleware for checking the Roles.

Example :

**PrivateRoute.tsx**

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

export const PrivateRoute = props => {
  // Get User info from local storage
  const userData = localStorage.getItem('user')
  const userRole = userData?.role;

  useEffect(() => {
    // do something here for async check
  },[])

  const hasPermission = useMemo(() => {
      // some condition checks for roles access for perticluar module
      return ...
  }, [userRole]);


  if (hasPermission) {
    return <Route {...props} />
  }

  return <Redirect to={'Some Path'} />
};
```

Comment: What actually happen that I want to render UI or navbar according to the role which came from when user logged in so where do I store that role which got from when user logged in If I store that thing in session cookie or localstorage than user can change it access the navbar which I want to show only SuperAdmin.

Comment: Ya, so you need to check that stuff in middleware and store it in your state or global state instead of localstorage.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that handling this kind of authorization is not enough on the frontend side. You can ask your backend to give you whether the user is ADMIN or SUPERADMIN or whatever. Then you can store this authentication status in a state management, so you'd easily access that after.

For implementing different situations, You can use guard some routes or render components conditionally considering which type the user is.

In my opinion, `HOCs` (wrapping the components with them) & `conditional rendering` can help you with RBAC.

Comment: Yes I am getting the role when user logged in you have any idea how to store that role in state what actually happening on page refresh the state are clear so I am unable to implement these.

Comment: If you are using redux you can use `redux-persist`. Otherwise, use local storage for saving user role or refetch user role whenever App component is mounted.